# Prove that if $f(n+1) > f(n)$ then $\forall n\in N, n\leq f(n)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

The whole problem is "Let $f : \mathbb N → \mathbb N$ be a strictly increasing function, that is, for each $n \in \mathbb N$ we have that $f(n + 1) > f(n)$. Prove that
$\forall n \in \mathbb N$ we have that $n \le f(n)$."

I have no idea how to start it, particularly how to get to a spot to compare $n$ and $f(n)$. Any help is welcome, thank you!

Comment: Have you tried induction?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4029998/42969

Comment: The *somewhat* *confusing* key to the problem is that since $f:\Bbb{N} \to \Bbb{N},~$ then as indicated in the answer of Mike, you must have that $f(1) \geq 1.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: $f(1) \ge 1$ [why is that]. Then use induction: Assume that, for some $n \ge 1$, that $j \le f(j)$ for all integers $j \le n$, and in particular that $n \le f(n)$, and so $n+1 \le f(n)+1$. Then use the fact that $f(n+1) > f(n)$ and that $f(n+1)$ must be an integer to see that $f(n+1) \ge f(n)+1 \ge n+1$.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the natural ones starting from 1.
Note that for $f$ to be a function, there must be $f(1)$ and necessarily $ 1\leq f(1)$(because f may not be surjective).Now, assuming that's true for $n$,this is

$n\leq f(n)$  then $ n+1\leq f(n) +1 \leq f(n)+f(1)\leq f(n+1)$, because f is strictly increasing. Note that the fact that $f(n+1) > f(n)$ then there must exist a natural $k$ such that $f(n)+k=f(n+1)$, since $k$ belongs to the naturals occurs $ 1 \leq k$.